# Updating images with dynamic input fields - Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, dynamic, updating

I'm making a cms with Laravel where i can dynamically add file inputs and store images.

This is my HTML and controller to store images:

```
<div v-for="file in files">
    <div class="textareaBlock">
        <label></label>
        <input type="file" name="image[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    $fileRequests = request()->file('image');

    if($fileRequests != NULL){
        foreach ($fileRequests as $fileRequest) {
            $fileRequest->store('images', 'public');
            $file = new File;
            $file->file = $fileRequest->hashName();
            $page->files()->save($file);
        }
    }
```

Now I'm having trouble updating the images if I'm not updating all of them. If i'm uploading 1 image, I'm getting the error: undefined offset 1. This is because I only uploaded 1 out of 2 input fields so it's only getting 1 out of 2 requests. If i'm uploading 2 out of 2 input fields it's working fine.

This is the code for updating the images:

```
    $files = File::all()->where('page_id', $page->id);
    $fileRequests = request()->file('image');

    $i=0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {

        $fileRequests[$i]->store('images', 'public');
        $file->file = $fileRequests[$i]->hashName();
        $i++;

        $page->files()->save($file);

    }
```

So my question is: How can I solve this problem if I'm not updating all of the every single time. Or is there a better way to do this in general? (I can imagine)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

`if (isset($fileRequests))`

This should check to see that the image array isset, as opposed to checking to see if the array exists - the undefined offset 1 is notifying you that the array element does not currently exist, rather than it is set. Otherwise you will need to make an exception for when there is only one image.

Comment: I used if(isset($filerequests[$i])) to solve the problem. Thank you so much for your answer!